# VirtualBox Vagrant inaccessible when VPN'd into local network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn, vagrant

I have a Vagrant configured VM running on a Windows 10 machine on my home network. I have the Vagrant public bridged network settings configured successfully so that I can access that guest VM from other machines on that network, not just the host. For instance I work on my laptop and I'm able to SSH to the guest VM IP without issue.

This all works great until I try to do the same thing accessing it from outside the network. My router supports VPN connections, so I set that up and I'm able to reach all the other devices on my network using private IPs (e.g. some local webserver I have running outside of a VM is accessible). I'm able to reach the Windows 10 host machine but when I try to reach the guest VM IP it hangs.

I think it could be that the VPN puts me on a separate subnet (e.g. guest VM IP is `192.168.29.125` and when on the VPN my laptop is assigned something like `192.168.0.35`). Does anyone have any ideas on how to allow a device that is on the network via a VPN connection to access a bridged network guest VM? I'm able to access the host machine, but not the guest VM running on that host.

Relevant Vagrantfile

```
    # Set up shared folders for local syncing
    override.vm.network 'private_network', :ip => IP_ADDRESS[:rails]

    # Windows and accessible on the network
    override.vm.network 'public_network'
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else finds this, I ended up solving this by directing connections at the host and enabling port forwarding in the Vagrant file.

For instance I wanted SSH and our app SSL port open (22 and 3443).

My host IP was something like 192.168.29.125

My Vagrant got an IP like 192.168.29.130

I was previously trying to VPN And connect to 192.168.29.130 on those ports but it would just timeout. I added lines like:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 22
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3443, host: 3443
```

Then I direct my connections to the host PC, which then forwards those connections to the VM. So rather than `ssh vagrant@192.168.29.130` it becomes `ssh vagrant@192.168.29.125` which then gets forwarded to 192.168.29.130